# How to trigger didReceiveAttrs in Ember component

Tags: ember.js

Using version 2.17. I have an Ember component inside an `/edit` route with a controller:

```
// edit.hbs
{{ingredient-table recipe=model ingredients=model.ingredients}}
```

Inside my component, I am using a `didRecieveAttrs` hook to loop through `ingredients` on render, create proxy objects based off of each, and then build an ingredient table using those proxy objects.

```js
// ingredient-table.js

didReceiveAttrs() {
  let uniqueIngredients = {};

  this.get('ingredients').forEach((ingredient) => {
    // do some stuff
  })

  this.set('recipeIngredients', Object.values(uniqueIngredients));
}
```

I also have a `delete` action, which I invoke when a user wishes to delete a row in the ingredient table. My `delete` action looks like this:

```js
// ingredient-table.js

deleteIngredient(ingredient) {
  ingredient.deleteRecord();

  ingredient.save().then(() => {
    // yay! deleted!
  })
}
```

Everything mentioned above is working fine. The problem is that the deleted ingredient row remains in the table until the page refreshes. It should disappear immediately after the user deletes it, without page refresh. I need to trigger the `didReceiveAttrs` hook again. If I manually call that hook, all my problems are solved. But I don't think I should be manually calling it.

Based on the docs, it is my understanding that this hook will fire again on page load, and on re-renders (not initiated internally). I'm having some trouble figuring out what this means, I guess. Here's what I've tried:

1) calling `ingredients.reload()` in the promise handler of my `save` in `ingredient-table.js` (I also tried `recipe.reload()` here).

2) creating a controller function that calls `model.ingredients.reload()`, and passing that through to my component, then calling it in the promise handler. (I also tried `model.reload()` here).

Neither worked. Am I even using the right hook?

Comment: `deleteRecord` only marks record as deleted but doesn't save, should you use `destroyRecord` instead? see https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.Model/methods/deleteRecord?anchor=deleteRecord

Comment: I call `save` afterward so I think I should be all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `recipeIngredients` is the items listed in the table. If that is the case; please remove the code within `didReceiveAttrs` hook and make `recipeIngredients` a computed property within the component. Let the code talk:

```
// ingredient-table.js

recipeIngredients: Ember.computed('ingredients.[]', function() {
    let uniqueIngredients = {};

    this.get('ingredients').forEach((ingredient) => {
        // do some stuff
    })

    return Object.values(uniqueIngredients)
})
```

My guess is `didReceiveAttrs` hook is not triggered again; because the array `ingredients` passed to the component is not changed; so `attrs` are not changed. By the way; do your best to rely on Ember's computed properties whenever possible; they are in the hearth of Ember design.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. Is there, in your opinion, ever a good time to use component hooks? I saw some articles while searching that mentioned they may be deprecated soon, but I could not find anything in the Ember guides that indicated the same.

Comment: My motto regarding the component hooks is; do not use them if possible; like in your case. `CP`s are really helpful for that. If you are heavily relying on them in your code base; it is an indicator for me that you are doing sth. wrong in terms of the overall design.

Other than that; when dealing with third party libraries such as jQuery plugins to be used; you have no chance to ignore them. Most of the times you do some initialization in `didInsertElement` and do some cleanup within `willDestroyElement`.

It is best practice to decide using them on a case by case basis. Hope this helps:)